# Shell scripting in controlled web environment

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, iis

I'm working on some web-based tools for our IT department, and need to launch a PowerShell script to do remote maintenance queries prior to loaning out a laptop.

I have an existing web-based registry of the laptop inventory, when one is loaned out we get the borrower to log in before they leave to ensure their profile is on the machine. At that point, I would like to query the laptop using a PowerShell script collecting information from it which would feed to the database and show on the display page.

The page itself is restricted to IT personnel, and our environments are very homogeneous -- everyone is running Windows (7 or 10) and IE (10 or 11).

I can launch a PowerShell script server-side easily enough from the VB code.

[ CommandToRun is a textbox, PStext an output span ]

```
        Dim app = New Process()
        Dim psi As ProcessStartInfo = app.StartInfo
        psi.FileName = "powershell.exe"
        psi.Arguments = CommandToRun.Text
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        psi.RedirectStandardError = True
        psi.UseShellExecute = False

        PStext.InnerHtml &= "<br/>Launching app: " & psi.FileName & " " & psi.Arguments
        app.Start()
        app.WaitForExit(5000)
        PStext.InnerHtml &= "<br/>OUTPUT<br/><pre>" & app.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() & "</pre>"
        PStext.InnerHtml &= "<br/>ERROR<br/><pre>" & app.StandardError.ReadToEnd() & "</pre>"
```

But it runs as the local system which does not have the authority to run remote PS commands. Lacking Administrator status, the server cannot execute anything on remote computers, therefore cannot query the laptop being loaned out.

I found a Javascript client-side solution that looks easy enough:

```
            function tryLaunch(commandtoRun, commandParms) {
                // Instantiate the Shell object and invoke its execute method.
                var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
                // Invoke the execute method.  
                oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun, commandParms, "", "open", "1");
            }
```

But it gets a **Permission denied** error launching the shell.

Other sources have had the same JavaScript with "WScript.Shell" as the ActiveXObject parameter -- that fails on the construction, whereas the "Shell.Application" version fails on the ShellExecute command.

---

I know what I'm doing is intentionally disallowed, as its usually a pretty dangerous idea to allow web servers to launch code on clients, and portability issues kill even the most well-meaning ideas -- but like I said, this is a very controlled and homogeneous environment.

So ... my questions:

1. Am I missing an obviously better way to do this?
2. Should I focus on trying to make PS scripts run on the client?  ( If so, any clues?? )
3. Should I focus on running the script server-side with different
   access rights?  ( Can I shell as the web site user? I have their
   "user" object from AD )
4. Am I ignoring some capability of IIS to install a PS script as an
   application using an Administrator account? (Seems like this should exist, which means I'm probably looking right at it and not seeing it. )

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 The basic rule is that IIS runs in a completely different context.

Comment: That URL is not allowed by my employer -- anything useful on it that can't be summarized?

Comment: I don't believe it is too large an article for you to read on your phone, or once you get back home. I also summarized it in a short sentence above.

Comment: Having read the article, I see why you suggested it -- because you wrote it.  

Other than that, I see no real connection, nor answer, to my questions.  My question does not refer to, nor is it affected by, the differences between development and production environments (the thrust of your article); nor is there anything in the article about running scripts client-side, nor even any suggestions on other ways I could accomplish the same functionality.